# How to get specific JSON object based on some variable?

Tags: java, android, json

when there is only one object, i dont have problem to retrieve variable from database
but when i want to retrive variable from only user1 or user2 the text in android doesnt appear anything.

this is my array from php code

```
{"users":[{"id":"5","name":"user1","updated_at":"2020-10-21 13:35:10"},{"id":"6","name":"user2","updated_at":"2020-10-21 11:29:53"}]}
```

and this my java code

```
private void getData(String name) {
    String tag_string_req = "get";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_data;
    list_data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET,
            AppConfig.URL_GET, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("users");
                for (int a = 0; a < jsonArray.length(); a++) {
                    JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(a);
                    String pengguna = jsonObject.getString("name");
                    if (pengguna.contains(name)) {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        map.put("updated_at", json.getString("updated_at"));
                        list_data.add(map);
                    }
                    update_time.setText(list_data.get(0).get("updated_at"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

}
```

my question is how to get specific JSON object based on some variable? so the text in android only show text based on user.

**edit :** the problem already solved by some edit in php code, so only the object fetching from database based on user.

my response in android

```
{"users":[{"id":"6","name":"user2","updated_at":"2020-10-21 13:35:10"}]}
```

the problem right now is the textview doesnt show me the value although the response already correct

Comment: SUGGESTION: Step through your code in the debugger (e.g. "Debug" your app in Android Studio) and see if `if (pengguna.contains(name)) {...}` is ever true.  I suspect you might have an empty list...

Answer (score 0):

You can look up to follow this :

`JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();`

`jsonObject.getJSONObject("key");`

It will resolve your problem, I think.